# Tornado http server's bind method

Tags: python, tornado

In httpserver.py, there is a `bind` method, at the end of this method is the code like this:

```
sock.bind(sockaddr) 
sock.listen(128) 
self._sockets[sock.fileno()] = sock 
if self._started: 
self.io_loop.add_handler(sock.fileno(), self._handle_events, 
                         ioloop.IOLoop.READ)
```

It means when a socket connected, and trigger `ioloop.IOLoop.READ` event , call `self._handle_events`, right?

But every client will generate a new file descriptor, right?

So how ioloop monitor client's socket connect via `sock.fileno()`? (httpserver's bind method only called once)

Answer (score 0):

I just had a quick look at the source, and it seems to work like this:

Tornado doesn't monitor the sockets itself, it passes this job onto the operating system, using `epoll` (Linux) or `select`. The call to `self.io_loop.add_handler` just adds a callback for when a new connection is available.

Client connections are set up by `self._handle_events`, which creates a new `HTTPConnection` for each new connection recieved by the socket. The communication socket used by each `HTTPConnection` is a new socket created by calling `sock.accept()`. The server continues accepting connections on the same socket as before.

so in summary:

- Yes, the io_loop calls `self._handle_events` when a new connection is detected on the socket.
- No, the socket is reused for new connections. In stead a new `HTTPConnection` object is created for each client, with a separate socket for communication.
- The io_loop doesn't need to actively monitor the socket. It passes the duty to the operating system using `epoll` or `select`. The actual communication with the clients is done by the `HTTPConnection` objects.

I think the key thing to understand, is that the socket here is just used for accepting new connections. When a connection is accepted using `sock.accept()`, this returns a new socket for communication, which is then attached to a `HTTPConnection` object.